# Improving efficiency of std::string in a compiler

Tags: c++, performance, stdin, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I'm attempting to build a scanner for a compiler of a **C** like language and am getting caught up on an efficient way to generate tokens... I have a scan function:

```
vector<Token> scan(string &input);
```

And also a main function, which reads in a lexically correct file and removes comments. (the language does not support `/* , */` comments) I am using a DFA with maximal munch to generate tokens... and I'm pretty sure that part of the scanner is reasonably efficient. However the scanner does not handle large files well, because they all end up in one string... and all of the concatenation of 1000 lines of a file with line 1001 is breaking the scanner. Unfortunately my FSM can not deal with comments because they are allowed to contain any Unicode and other odd characters. I was wondering... is there a better way to go from a file in stdin, to a vector of tokens, keeping in mind that the function scan must take a single string and, return a single vector, and all tokens must be in a single vector at the end of scanning... Anyway, here is the code which "scans": Please don't laugh at my bad idea too hard :)

```
string in = "";
string build;
while(true)
{
    getline(cin, build);
    if( cin.eof() ) 
    break;

    if(build.find ("//") != string::npos)
    build = build.substr(0, build.find("//",0));

    in += " " + build;
}

try {
  vector<Token> wlpp = scan(in);
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that you might want to consider:

```
in += " " + build;
```

Is very inefficient and probably not want you want in that loop, but that doesn't seem to be where you're running in to problems. (at the very least, get some idea about the size of your inputs and do `in.reserve(size)` before that.

The better design for your scanner might be as a class that wraps the input file as an `istream_iterator<Token>` and implement an appropriate `operator>>` for Token. If you really wanted it in a vector, you could then do something like `vector<Token> v(istream_iterator<Token>(cin), istream_iterator<Token>());` and be done with it. Your `operator>>` would then just swallow comments and populate a token before returning.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, however it gives me the idea of using a string stream instead of the + operator, Do you know how that compares to the using istream_iterator?